Github actions появляются в списке, но не запускаются
Я создал файл в папке .github/workflows/main.yml, но после того, как я залил его на гитхаб, ничего не произошло, а именно никаких действий не началось
main.yml
name: linting, testing, building
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  pipeline:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ 17.x ]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Staring Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: install modules
        run: npm install
      - name: build production project
        run: npm run build:prod
        if: always()
      - name: linting typescript
        run: npm run lint:ts
        if: always()
      - name: linting css
        run: npm run lint:scss
      - name: unit testing
        if: always()
        run: npm run test:unit
      - name: build storybook
        run: npm run storybook:build
        if: always()
      - name: screenshot testing
        run: npm run test:ui:ci
        if: always()

package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --env port=3000",
    "build:prod": "webpack  --env mode=production",
    "build:dev": "webpack  --env mode=development",
    "lint:ts": "eslint \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "lint:ts:fix": "eslint \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\" --fix",
    "lint:scss": "npx stylelint \"**/*.scss\"",
    "lint:scss:fix": "npx stylelint \"**/*.scss\" --fix",
    "test:unit": "jest --config ./config/jest/jest.config.ts",
    "test:ui": "npx loki test",
    "test:ui:ok": "npx loki approve",
    "test:ui:ci": "loki --requireReference --reactUri file:./storybook-static",
    "test:ui:report": "npm run test:ui:json && npm run test:ui:html",
    "test:ui:json": "node scripts/generate-visual-json-report.js",
    "test:ui:html": "reg-cli --from .loki/report.json --report .loki/report.html",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -c ./config/storybook",
    "storybook:build": "build-storybook -c ./config/storybook"


скрин из main.yml https://i.sstatic.net/UmNL5UqE.png
скрин из вкладки actions https://i.sstatic.net/65g0gy6B.png

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
